# Pointing a subdomain to an application hosted on IIS on another server

Tags: web, iis-7, dns

I have a web server hosting a domain name , say www.example.com. Now, I would like to host a subdomain, say newExample.example.com which is hosted on another server.

Now, I understand that this is possible by entering, in the admin control panel, an 'A' record  which points the subdomain to the ip address. But, what if I would like to point my subdomain to an address such as : 11.11.11.11/newExampleWebsite . Is this possible?

The '11.11.11.11/newExampleWebsite' is hosted as an application in IIS 7.

Thanks,

Comment: do you want redirect newExample.example.com to 11.11.11.11/newExampleWebsite ?

Comment: Redirect is an option I have considered and it works but on redirection the web address in the IE address bar changes to the redirected page which isn't ideal. This is why I looking at an 'A' record option as in this case, the address remains as newExample.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found an elegant solution to this.

I have used the hosting control panel to point the subdomain to the IP address instead of 11.11.11.11/newExampleWebsite. But, to ensure 'newExampleWebsite' is displayed when navigating to newExample.example.com we need do the following in IIS.

- Create a new website in IIS.
- Give it a name, such as 'newExampleWebsite'.
- The target directory will be same as the one being used for '11.11.11.11/newExampleWebsite' .
- Enter the host name as 'newExample.example.com'.
- IIS takes care of resolving the correct website based.

[image]

The kicker is I had to host two subdomains and I just pointed both to this IP address and let IIS resolve these.